# Retrieve Java object by ID from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an Android app and I am trying to retrieve an object of the class `User.java` by ID from its Firebase pertinent table. I would like to know how to get it from Java side, as long as I tried the examples stated in [Firebase Official docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html) but none of them is working for me.

Taking this SO question as example, I want a method with the following interface:

```
public User readUser(String userId);
```

In other words, I want to execute:

`readUser(-lnnROTBVv6FznK81k3n)`

and retrieve the associated `User` object

Thanks

**--------------------------------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------**:

I managed to get the value with this code:

```
public void retrieveUser(final String email){
        firebaseUsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if(messageSnapshot.getKey().equals(Email.encodeID(email))){

                        retrievedUser = messageSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
        });
    }
```

Please not retrievedUser is a class `attribute`, thus a `field`. I am accessing that field from the code, but even I see it takes the value on the debugger, **it is being null on the calling code**.

Any hint? Can´t I just return it in the method itself, so it would be?:

```
public User retrieveUser(final String email);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

so here is the soultion, I didn't put it in a method though.

```
final String uid = "your Uid here"; 
        // Get a reference to users
        Firebase ref = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL_USERS);
        // Attach an listener to read our users
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot user: snapshot.getChildren()) {
               //this is all you need to get a specific user by Uid
                    if (user.getKey().equals(uid)){
                        wantedUser = user.getValue(User.class);
                    }
               //**********************************************

                }
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: " + wantedUser.getName());
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, could you please place the full method? I am not sure about how can I retrieve the actual user as an object

Comment: I tried to make it as a method, but you have an inner class here which cause issues when you call a local field from inside it. however you can define a user Instance and call this code to instantiate it. then you can do what you want with that object.

Comment: Thanks pal, could you please translate that into code? I don't quite get it

Comment: could you attach the full code to see where is the problem

Comment: That would be another question, could you please put the code you first suggested into a method that returns an User.java object? (I don´t care if you return a ficticial User object or any Java object)