# Retrieve Java object from Firebase given UID

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am very new to asynchronous programming and I am a little confused about how to retrieve a Java object given a unique ID.  I have followed the examples given on the Firebase website about structuring and reading data, but I am unsure how to retrieve a specific object without retrieving the entire list.  I have seen people retrieve the entire list and iterate through it until finding the correct object, however I feel like this is very inefficient and not the ideal method.

My firebase database structure

```
{
  "chats" : {
    "defcon69" : {
      "chatMembers" : {
        "abc con" : true,
        "rGmgSVGcq4WE6kehY4HH5z7ntIQ2" : true
      },
      "chatMessages" : {
        "-KmYAcmmvmSfMrOYnAtR" : "-KmYAcmmvmSfMrOYnAtR",
        "-KmYAmNmjWExC1gcCuF8" : "-KmYAmNmjWExC1gcCuF8",
        "-KmZuNNG6lZCn_HeA1aq" : "-KmZuNNG6lZCn_HeA1aq"
      },
      "chatName" : "FLT",
      "chatText" : "hey ",
      "chatTime" : 1497415382731,
      "chatUUID" : "defcon69"
    }
  },
  "messages" : {
    "defcon69" : {
      "-KmYAcmmvmSfMrOYnAtR" : {
        "messageText" : "test",
        "messageTime" : 1497386352516,
        "messageUUID" : "-KmYAcmmvmSfMrOYnAtR",
        "messageUser" : "con"
      },
      "-KmYAf3FKCzJyL8-3_9U" : {
        "messageText" : "hey",      
        "messageTime" : 1497386361825,
        "messageUUID" : "-KmYAf3FKCzJyL8-3_9U",
        "messageUser" : "con"
      }
  }
}
```

I am specifically trying to retrieve a message object given it's uid.

[Example of iterating through list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897386/retrieve-java-object-by-id-from-firebase)

[Structuring Firebase data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data)

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: It would also be good if you'd posted some of the code you've already tried. There are literally hundreds of examples of [querying the Firebase Database from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bandroid%5D+query) here on Stack Overflow. Seeing what you have tried, makes it easier to give help specific to where you are stuck.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have been successful using the example I provided of iterating through the entire list, however this seems incredible inefficient if the list begins getting in the length of thousands or 10s of thousands.

Answer (score 0):

there are  a simple function to do that i share an example

```
    String uid="your  uid";
  DatabaseReference ref= mDatabase.child("messages").child(uid).getRef();

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                     Message m=dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                     // your message is here do what you want
                  }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                  Log.i("dberror",databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

did you look at this it's simple,
and if you want single value event listener may because you want use the Value one time so try to use

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...);
```